# PHP Datetime to JSON Format

Tags: javascript, php, json, datetime

I have php datetime output like this

`#02/11/2017 17:59:16 PM#`

How do I convert it into json format

`\/Date(1428192447278+0800)\/"`

I tried something like this

`var date = new Date(toJsonDateTime);`

No luck!

Comment: There is no such thing as a special "JSON format". JSON itself is simply serialized data, for arbitrary data. So all you have to do is "json serialize" whatever data you want. PHP offers the function `json_encode()` for that.

Comment: A time value with an offset is an unusual representation of a date. In Firefox and Safari, `JSON.stringify(new Date())` gives a string like "2017-02-11T13:07:16.628Z", which seems more sensible.

Comment: Do you really have `#` at start and end of the date?

Answer (score 0):

To make json you need `key:value` pair, Use `json_encode` like this

```
echo json_encode(['date'=>$yourDate]);
```